# Mapping texture to sphere using THREE.DecalGeometry

Tags: javascript, three.js

I am using [THREE.DecalGeometry](https://github.com/spite/THREE.DecalGeometry) to map images to my globe.

Although I finally have them appearing at the correct location, I am having some difficulty with the orientation.

[image: dodgy hotspot]

[image: ok hotspot]

The green squares are the hotspots, I could live with them being rotated as the will finally have transparency so I can ignore the corners. but stretching and clipping is no good here.

I think its the direction vector that is the issue, but I don't know what I'm supposed to be supplying here.

```
    function getDecalGeometry(position, direction){
    var decalGeometry = new THREE.DecalGeometry(  
        earthMesh, // it has to be a THREE.Mesh
        position, // THREE.Vector3 in world coordinates  
        direction, // THREE.Vector3 specifying the orientation of the decal  
        new THREE.Vector3(25,25,25), // THREE.Vector3 specifying the size of the decal box  
        new THREE.Vector3(1,1,1) // THREE.Vector3 specifying what sides to clip (1-clip, 0-noclip)  
    );
    return decalGeometry;
}

function getDecalMaterial(){
    var decalMaterial = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial( {
        map: THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture( 'img/hotspot.png' ), 
        transparent: true, 
        depthTest: true,
        depthWrite: false,
        polygonOffset: true,
        polygonOffsetFactor: -4,
    });
    return decalMaterial;
}
```

Comment: How are you calculating the direction? Take a look from line 283 [View Source HERE](https://www.clicktorelease.com/code/decal-splatter/). Specifically how the variable r vector is calculated.

Comment: @2pha I am struggling to find the correct vector for direction. I am using the vertex that is used for position as I can't find a normal. Should I be using a face normal for direction? If so then how to get the point of the face as it has 3 vertices attached.

Comment: I have opened new question with simple example - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34177750/how-to-set-correct-direction-for-a-decal-using-three-decalgeometry

Comment: Where is your old question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34155602/add-a-hotspot-on-3d-sphere-surface (adding hotspots to a sphere)?

Comment: @lowtechsun - sorry I removed that question as it became irrelevant. Do you need help with something?

Comment: @Neil ..yes I am trying to get hotspots going in either a cubemap or an equirectangular sphere, with threejs.. looking for a good tut on this specifically or how to get there.