# How to set correct direction for a decal using THREE.DecalGeometry

Tags: javascript, three.js

I am trying to understand how to add decals to a mesh using [THREE.DecalGeometry](https://github.com/spite/THREE.DecalGeometry)

I am adding decals to the vertex on each face - **face.a**, I've tried using the face normal and arbitrary Vector3 to define the direction for the decal.

I cannot understand why all the decals are not being created correctly. Where am I go wrong with the direction? Is the face normal not correct?

```
function addObjects(){
    var geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(200, 200, 200, 8, 8, 8);
    var material = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({color: 0xff0000});
    cube = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);

    // addWireframeHelper(cube, 0xffffff, 1);

scene.add(cube);
  THREE.ImageUtils.crossOrigin = 'Anonymous';
    var texture = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture( 'http://i.imgur.com/RNb17q7.png' );
    geometry.faces.forEach(function(face){
    var index = face.a;
    var vertex = geometry.vertices[index];
    var direction = new THREE.Vector3(0,1,0);
    addDecal(cube, vertex, direction, texture);
})
}

function addDecal(mesh, position, direction, texture){
var size = 16;
var decalGeometry = new THREE.DecalGeometry(  
    mesh, 
    position, 
    direction,   
    new THREE.Vector3(size,size,size), 
    new THREE.Vector3(1,1,1)   
);

var decalMaterial = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial( {
    map: texture,
    transparent: true, 
    depthTest: true,
    depthWrite: false,
    polygonOffset: true,
    polygonOffsetFactor: -4,
});

    var m = new THREE.Mesh( decalGeometry, decalMaterial );
    mesh.add(m);
}
```

This is the hotspot 64px x 64px

[image: hotspot]

This is how they are getting mapped...

[image: cube]

Why are some decals stretched?

I have setup a [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/2ykggtm1/9/)

**EDIT:**

Using SphereBufferGeometry suggested by WestLangley, I am now happy that this solution will work for me.

[image]

Comment: Not an answer, but (1) type `renderer.info` into the console to see you have 769 geometries, and 769 draw calls per frame. Also, your cube has 128 faces per side, when 2 should be sufficient. (2) Decals may not orient properly when the face-normal is parallel to the y-axis. Try a sphere. (3) Why are you using decals instead of `THREE.Sprite`s or `THREE.Points`?

Comment: @WestLangley (1) confirmed 769 and 769 (2) sphere example added (3) Both Sprite and Points orient to the camera and don't sit flat on the sphere like a decal would. I may have to compromise and workaround this somehow with a sprite or points.

Comment: (1) Your demo with invisible sphere and 1 big decal. http://jsfiddle.net/db6j8pc3/3/ -- just to see what you are really doing... (2) Yes, instead of decals, I meant to suggest `THREE.PlaneBufferGeometry`.

Comment: @WestLangley Do you think it would be possible to create a plane to take each decal and curve it to suit the shape of the sphere? Then I could position these meshes where I need them?

Comment: Use a sector of a `SphereBufferGeometry` for your decal if you want it curved: http://jsfiddle.net/db6j8pc3/4/

Comment: @WestLangley See updated screenshot, I am really happy with your idea using section of a `SphereBufferGeometry` as I can size using phi and theta. Please add as answer to take well earned bounty!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than using `THREE.DecalGeometry`, for your use case a sector of a `SphereGeometry` will be sufficient, and computationally less-expensive.

```
var geometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry( radius, widthSegments, heightSegments, phiStart, phiLength, thetaStart, thetaLength );
```

three.js r.143